# Where should environment secrets for integration tests be stored?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am starting a new java project and I want to run some integration tests with the maven-failsafe-plugin. The tests will connect to remote redis and sql databases.
I am wondering where should I put the credentials and connection strings for the servers.

In the application code, the secrets will be stored in environment variables (azure function app settings, to be precise).
Can I put them in some external properties file and reference it in the failsafe-plugin configuration? I found a page about system properties in the documentation, but having the secrets in pom file that is git-versioned is not safe.